# URL redirect - append onto the end of the link

Tags: http, url, redirect, glassfish

I am using Glassfish V3

I currently have users that access my application using http://mydomain.com/workbench

I want it so that if the user doesn't put the workbench part that they are directed to it

E.g.

'http://mydomain.com' --> 'http://mydomain.com/workbench'

'http://mydomain.com/workbench' (this shouldn't redirect

'http://mydomain.com/PDA' (this shouldn't redirect)

I have tried using redirct_n but it hasn't solved the problem; as I did this:

redirect_1 from=/my-app url=http://mydomain.com/workbench

for obvious reasons this creates an infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this approach probably isn't working for you. It's meant for status and error pages (e.g. 40x). If you need more complex rules I suggest looking into any of these solutions:
+ URL Rewriting from your app With a little help from the apps around (e.g., http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/)
+ Apache mod_proxy and mod_rewrite

Rgds,
Markus

Comment: Hi, i encountered this issue as well but my Web Server is using Apache Web Server 2.2 in server A and using Glassfish 3.1.2 as Apps Server in Server B. Is there any work around for my situation? As i understand from the solution given, it's more suitable to single box for Web and Apps server instead of different box and tools..